# Como contar a quantidade de vezes que um número ou mais se repete dentro de um vetor em c?

Tags: c

Preciso fazer esse exercício e estou travando na hora de realizar a contagem.
Faça um programa que leia um vetor de 8 posições e verifique se existem valores iguais e os escreva (cada número repetido deve aparecer somente uma vez na resposta)

Exemplo de saída:

```
<< Valores iguais >>
Entre com o número 1: 5
Entre com o número 2: 6
Entre com o número 3: 4
Entre com o número 4: 5
Entre com o número 5: -3
Entre com o número 6: -3
Entre com o número 7: -3
Entre com o número 8: 6
Valores repetidos: 5, 6, -3
```

Meu código até agora:

```
int main(){
    int vetor[8];
    int i,x,j,k;
    int newVetor[8];

    int n=0;    

    printf("<< Valores iguais >>\n");

    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        printf("Entre com o numero %i: ",i+1);
        scanf("%i",&vetor[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<8;i++){
        for(x=i+1;x<8;x++){
            if(vetor[i] == vetor[x]){
                newVetor[n] = vetor[i]; 
                n++;    
            }
            else{}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma possível solução é, após a leitura dos elementos do vetor, ordená-lo e depois verificar eventuais duplicidades.

Answer (score 0):

Destaco o seguinte trecho do seu código:

```
for(i=0; i<8;i++){
        for(x=i+1;x<8;x++){
           printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", vetor[i], vetor[x], n);
            if(vetor[i] == vetor[x]){
                newVetor[n] = vetor[i];
                n++;
            }
            else{}
        }
    }
```

Ele até funciona bem se o usuário digita um número no máximo duas vezes, mas caso o usuário, por exemplo, digite o mesmo número nas oito entradas, a condição `vetor[i] == vetor[x]` sempre vai ser verdadeira e a varíavel  `n` atingiria, em tese, o valor 28. Digo em tese, porque quando `n` atinge o valor 8, a instrução `newVetor[n] = vetor[i]` começa a escrever fora dos limites do array newVetor, então, o comportamento do código não pode ser previamente definido.

Usando força bruta, daria para resolver o problema assim:

```
   int a = 0;
   int flag = 1;
    for(i=0; i<8;i++){
        for(x=i+1;x<8;x++){

            if(vetor[i] == vetor[x]){
                  //verifica se vetor[i] já foi incluído em newVetor
                  // e armazena o resultado na variável flag
                  // flag == 0 (já foi incluído) flag == 1 (ainda não foi incluído)
                  for(a = 0; a < n; a++){
                     if(vetor[i] == newVetor[a]){
                         flag = 0;
                     }
                  }
                  //se ainda não foi incluído, inclua o valor de vetor[i] em newVector
                  if(flag) {
                      newVetor[n] = vetor[i];
                  n++;
               }
            }
            //reseta o valor de flag para as próximas repetições
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

   printf("Valores repetidos: ");
   for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
      printf("%d ", newVetor[i]);
   }
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui

Answer (score 0):

Um dica, utilize o tamanho do vetor em uma variável ou calcule ele! Evite usar números "hard coded", pois assim se você mudar o tamanho dele, tem que mudar em vários lugares, dificultando a alteração/manutenção do seu código.

Segue o exemplo de acordo com o que você deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 8     

int main() {
    
    int vetor[LENGTH];     
        
    for(int i=0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        printf("Entre com o numero %i: ",i+1);
        scanf("%i",&vetor[i]);
    }    
        
    printf("Valores repetidos: ");    
    // Procura os repetidos   
    for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH ; j++) {    
        for(int k = j + 1; k < LENGTH; k++) {    
            if(vetor[j] == vetor[k])    
                printf("%d, ", vetor[k]);    
        }    
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso um `#define length 8` não seria melhor?

Comment: Sim, seria mesmo. Obrigado, irei editar.